# Can I acces other peoples calendar via the google calendar API?

Tags: php, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm currently working on a project where I have different users stored in a database and want to show the loged in users agenda with the help of google calendar API. 
I can acces all my agendas because of oAuth that I have for my personal account but I can't even request the primary calendar summary from another account. It gives the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I guess my personal oAuth doesn't give me the acces to any other account except for my own.
Is there a way to get the acces to other users their agenda if I have their email account (which is also the id to their primary calendar) or would they all need their own oAuth authenticiation?

I read something about serviceaccounts for oAuth, would that be the way to go or is their an easier way that I don't know yet?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think they need to generate their own oAuth. Might be best to create a "master calendar" that everyone in your group has access to.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reason you can't access a specific user's Google account data unless your app ask him for consent.

The "user's consent" is a one-time action and once given, Google replies your callback url with an *access token* and a *refresh token*.

Since the access token has a short lifetime (=1hr) , you need to save the refresh token (infinite lifetime) and store it for each user. Use this refresh token to access the API and retrieve user's data.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2